# A music playlist has 2 songs of different lengths. If it's played on repeat for an hour how long is each song played?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, statistics, functions, data-analysis

2 songs are played on repeat sequentially. Song A is 5 minutes long, song B is 4 minutes long. After one hour how many times is each song played?

This question has troubled me for a while now. I’ve done so much research and I can’t seem to find a way to find the answer anywhere. 
**Please help!!**

Comment: Basically you are looking for positive integer solutions (x,y) when $5x+4y =60$ or exceed 60 first time.

Comment: How about A is played 7 times and B is played 6 times.

Comment: Song A followed by Song B takes a total of 9 minutes. Find out how many times that can happen in sixty minutes, then just check what will happen in the remaining time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily  by reasoning. assume A started first then 5+4,5+4.....6 times  (Greatest integer function ${60  \over 9}$  times )+ 5= 59 .So A completed seven and B ran 6 times +1 minute long . If B started first by same logic A ran 6 and B 7 times +2 minute extra.